# How do I make a meta_query OR relation work?

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

Here's are wp_query args:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sportpages'
    ,'post_status' => 'publish'
    ,'posts_per_page' => 1000
    ,'post_parent' => 4738
    ,'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR'
        ,array(
            'key' => 'ecpt_sportgender_2'
            ,'value' => 'Boys'
            ,'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
        ,array(
            'key' => 'ecpt_sportgender_2'
            ,'value' => 'Both'
            ,'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

My results are odd.  I'm getting only the posts for Boys unless I swap Boys for Girls, in which case I get Girls.  The only way to get "Both" is to make it get ONLY Both, and not do the relationship.

The order in which I put them in there makes no difference.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried setting compare to `=`?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to do one of the following

- `'compare' => '='` (or leave it out, as it's the default)
- or... `'value' => $wpdb->esc_like( '%Boys%' )` (needs `global $wpdb;`)
- or... `'value' => $wpdb->esc_like( 'Boys' )` (needs `global $wpdb;`)

Comment: The compare = didn't work.  Escaping the values gives the result of Both, but not Boys.

Comment: "the result of Both, but not Boys"...? So only Girls? Then It's not _both_...

Comment: Also: Remove the `'post_parent' => 4738`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.  The query WAS returning the proper results, but the results were getting munged in some later code.  :(

Thanks for your time pondering this.